# Install Ubuntu directly to HDD from Win XP

Tags: system-installation, windows, hard-drive

New Ubuntu user here. I have an ancient Toshiba Satellite A80 laptop that I'd guess to be at least 8 yrs old. It's currently running Windows XP, can't boot from USB and has no floppy drive or CD drive.

Is there any way to download Ubuntu directly to the hard drive of this computer (not dual booting)? If it helps, there are 3 USB ports (although the BIOS won't boot from them).

Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57310/discussion-on-question-by-theo-c-install-ubuntu-directly-to-hdd-from-win-xp).

Answer (score 1):

So, there was a way to do this with WUBI, but WUBI is now abandoned and is no longer recommended.

Now, I also had this same issue with an older Dell desktop. What I ended up doing was using a [USB floppy drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00RXEWOAA) and loading up a standard 3.5" floppy with the [Plop Boot Manager](https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html), **which allows you to boot from USB even if the BIOS doesn't support it.** (The older BIOSes support booting from a USB floppy drive/CD drive)

Of course, you could also do the same thing with a USB CD/DVD drive (just burn PLOP to the CD)

Comment: The USB CD/DVD is probably cheaper and easier to find than floppies ;-)

Comment: @CelticWarrior Right, which is why I mentioned that as an alternative at the bottom. I already had a USB FDD and some floppies, so that's why I did it that way :)

Comment: OK, I'll try connecting an external CD drive with PLOP.

Comment: @TheoC With an external CD/DVD you don't need PloP. You can burn a Ubuntu DVD and boot from there directly.

Comment: @CelticWarrior - True, although being able to boot from USB is helpful. Of course, this is all assuming that the BIOS in question can boot from a USB CD drive and not just a USB FDD.